# How can I print the results of 2 for loops on the same line

Tags: java, android, string, formatting

I am trying to get the code to run so that the output looks like this,

```
91-100 | [][][][][][][][][]

81- 90 | [][][][][]

71- 80 | [][][][][][][][][][]

61- 70 | [][]

51- 60 | []

41- 50 | [][]

31- 40 |

21- 30 |

11- 20 |

 1- 10 | [][][]
```

But currently, my output is looking like this,

```
91-100 |

[][][][][][][][][]81- 90 |

[][][][][]71- 80 |

[][][][][][][][][][]61- 70 |

[][]51- 60 |

[]41- 50 |

[][]31- 40 |

21- 30 |

11- 20 |

 1- 10 |

[][][]
```

Here is my code:

```
 int[] buckets = new int[10];
 while(scan.hasNextLine()){            
     String line = scan.nextLine();
     String[] array = line.split(separator);
     String grade = array[1];
     int number =  Integer.parseInt(grade.trim());
     buckets[(number - 1)/10]++;           
 }
 for(int i = buckets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)// RELEVANT PARTS TO QUESTION
     System.out.printf("%2d-%3d |%n", i * 10 + 1, i * 10 + 10);
     for(int j = 0; j < buckets[i]; j++){
         System.out.print("[]");
     }
 }
```

I seem to be printing the `[]` on to the next line, but I can't seem to figure out how to put the `[]` on the line above. I tried using `printf(%d %d | %s%n)`, but that doesnt work too well from what i have tried and just creates more problems.
Is there anyway to move the `[]` back a line?

Comment: See if you can figure out a way to print out each line in **one** print statement.

Comment: I tried doing that, but my class TA's were saying that it would be difficult to format it correctly, and that I should go with the 2 for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `printf` prints a new line when you enter `%n`, I suggest using something like this (replace `%n` with a space, add `println` after the loop):

```
for(int i = buckets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print("%2d-%3d | ", i * 10 + 1, i * 10 + 10);
    for(int j = 0; j < buckets[i]; j++){
        System.out.print("[]");
    } 
    System.out.println("");
}
```

the `println` statement will give you the newline in the place you want.

Comment: I inserted that println statement, and it made the code look neater, but it simply placed the brackets on a new line entirely, and not side by side to the numbers like I'm trying to do

Comment: as long as `println` is after the loop, it shouldn't move the `[]` to the next line, did you make it `println` in the loop and get a vertical column of `[]`?
Don't forget to change the `%n` to ' '

Comment: My pleasure, and I should've specified both changes in the non-code part of the original version of the answer xD


Also, I suggest also taking a look at Michael Lihs' answer and picking an answer as the one that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the bucket string before the `printf` statement and then print the string at once like

```
 for (int i = buckets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {        
     String bucketsString = "";    

     for(int j = 0; j < buckets[i]; j++) 
         bucketsString = bucketsString.concat("[]");

     System.out.printf("%2d-%3d | %s %n", i * 10 + 1, i * 10 + 10, bucketsString);
 }
```

Comment: I like that.
Is a whole bunch of `concat`s faster than `print`s in addition to looking nicer?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but since `print` needs to interact with the system in some way, I guess `concat` should be faster since it's "Java internal". But don't know how `print` is actually implemented in Java - so it's a guess.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.printf()` and `System.out.println()` add a new line at the end. So just use `System.out.print()` and at the end of a line use `System.out.println()`

```
for(int i = buckets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)// RELEVANT PARTS TO QUESTION
    System.out.print("%2d-%3d |", i * 10 + 1, i * 10 + 10);
    for(int j = 0; j < buckets[i]; j++){
        System.out.print("[]");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget removing `%n`

Also, ninja'd :P